# How to get authorized user object in django-tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I need to get authorized user object in hydrate method, something like that:

```
class SalepointResource(ModelResource):
  def hydrate(self, bundle):
    user = bundle.request.user
```

But **request** here is empty **HttpRequest** object, and doesn't have user method, although user is authorized. Is there any way to get user object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With TastyPie 0.9.15, I find this works:

```
def hydrate_user(self, bundle):
    bundle.obj.user = bundle.request.user
    return bundle
```

with no need for subclassing `ModelResource`.  Here `user` is a `ForeignKey` of the model and the resource.
I'm posting this as an answer because although it looks simple, it took me a long time to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up authentication/authorization properly in tastypie?

Comment: Yes, both authentication and authorization is set, it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach, but I got around this problem by subclassing the `ModelResource` class and overriding some of its methods.  In `ModelResource` the `request` object (which contains `user`) is a parameter to the `obj_update` method but it is not passed on to the `full_hydrate` method, which in turn calls `hydrate`.  You have to make a few small changes to each of these methods to pass the `request` object all the way down the chain.

The method modifications are trivial.  In detail:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned, ValidationError
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.exceptions import NotFound, BadRequest, InvalidFilterError, HydrationError, InvalidSortError, ImmediateHttpResponse

class MyModelResource(ModelResource):
    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        ...
        bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle, request)
        ...

    def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        ...
        bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle, request)
        ...

    def full_hydrate(self, bundle, request=None):
        ...
        bundle = self.hydrate(bundle, request)
        ...

    def hydrate(self, bundle, request=None):
        ...
        return bundle
```

Then make your resource a subclass of this new class and override the new version of `hydrate`:

```
class MyModelResource(MyModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

    def hydrate(self, bundle, request):
        bundle.obj.updated_by_id = request.user.id
        return bundle
```

I haven't tested this thoroughly but it seems to work so far.  Hope it helps.